# How disabled auto white balance in Kinect 2.0 (Win)?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I develop chroma key effect for Kinect 2.0. In static image (only background) it's ok. But Kinect doing auto balance when people appear in frame  and colors is changing. Algorithm doesn't work in this case. How disabled auto white balance in Kinect 2.0 for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

The SDK doesn't give you any control over camera settings. You can read the camera settings using the [`ColorCameraSettings class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorcamerasettings.aspx), but you can't change them.

There was a thread in the official support forum about ["Auto Exposure Compensation"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a6ba4d8-8c78-4c43-9345-d4136382d629/auto-exposure-compensation?forum=kinectv2sdk), basically doing some post processing on the color image. Maybe you can do something like that.